# PeeWee sorts integer values as if they were strings

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

```
month_column = dc.Message.date_utc.month
year_column = dc.Message.date_utc.year
message_count = fn.Count(dc.Message.id)
yearmonthname_column = year_column.concat("_").concat(month_column).concat("_").concat(dc.User.name)
yearmonth_column = year_column.concat("_").concat(month_column)
query = (dc.Message
         .select(yearmonthname_column.alias('yearmonthname'), yearmonth_column.alias('yearmonth'), dc.User.name, message_count.alias("messages_count"), year_column.alias("year"), month_column.alias("month"))
         .join(dc.User)
         .where(dc.Message.posted_in == chatId)
         .group_by(yearmonthname_column)
         .order_by(message_count.desc())
         .order_by(month_column.cast('INTEGER')) # SORTING BY MONTH
         .order_by(year_column)
         )
```

Above, you can see my query. The problem here is: I want it to be sorted by `month` value as if it was number, but what I see as a result looks like:

```
"1", "10", "11", "12", "2"
```

Instead of:

```
"1", "2", "10", "11", "12"
```

Sorting by month happens in this line:

`.order_by(month_column.cast('INTEGER'))`

As you can see, I was trying to cast this value to `INTEGER`, but it actually didn't change anything.

Are there any simple fixes for this problem?

**EDIT:**

I've also noticed that there is no `cast` in final SQL code generated by peewee.

How I get it:

```
print(query.sql())
```

How it looks like:

```
('SELECT ((((date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc") || ?) || date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc")) || ?) || "t2"."name") AS yearmonthname, ((date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc") || ?) || date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc")) AS yearmonth, "t2"."name", Count("t1"."id") AS messages_count, date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc") AS year, date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc") AS month FROM "message" AS t1 INNER JOIN "user" AS t2 ON ("t1"."created_by_id" = "t2"."id") WHERE ("t1"."posted_in_id" = ?) GROUP BY ((((date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc") || ?) || date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc")) || ?) || "t2"."name") ORDER BY date_part(?, "t1"."date_utc")', ['year', '_', 'month', '_', 'year', '_', 'month', 'year', 'month', 220, 'year', '_', 'month', '_', 'year'])
```

And that's probably why it doesn't work. Do anyone know why is that happening?

Answer (score 3):

`.order_by(Message.month.cast('int'))` only works with Peewee v3.0.0 or later.  If you are using v2.x you have to use [`Cast()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Cast) as in `.order_by(Cast(Message.month, 'int'))`.  The `cast()` method was added with [this commit](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/baa615d4138400f0e2b62c16a0995dbfc3ce00a4).

Here is a working code:

```python
import datetime
import peewee
from peewee import *
from pprint import pprint

db = SqliteDatabase('/tmp/a.db')

class Message(Model):
    month = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.drop_tables(models=[Message], safe=True)
db.create_tables([Message])

Message.create(month="7")
Message.create(month="8")
Message.create(month="9")
Message.create(month="10")
Message.create(month="11")
Message.create(month="12")
Message.create(month="1")
Message.create(month="2")
Message.create(month="3")
Message.create(month="4")
Message.create(month="5")
Message.create(month="6")

m = []
query = Message.select().order_by(Message.month)
for q in query:
    m.append(q.month)
pprint(m) #=> ['1', '10', '11', '12', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

m = []
query = Message.select().order_by(Message.month.cast("INTEGER"))
for q in query:
    m.append(q.month)
pprint(m) #=> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']

# for Peewee 2.x
m = []
query = Message.select().order_by(Cast(Message.month, 'int'))
for q in query:
    m.append(q.month)
pprint(m) #=> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']

pprint(query.sql())
#=> ('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."month" FROM "message" AS "t1" ORDER BY '
#    'CAST("t1"."month" AS int)',
#    [])

print(peewee.__version__) #=> 3.0.18
```

Comment: The problem is: as you can see from question, I do exactly that and it doesn't work. Maybe it's a problem with getting month from utc date (`dc.Message.date_utc.month`). What is a type of month calculated this way?

Comment: I think I've found why `cast` doesn't work. Check out `EDIT` in my question. It's not included in generated SQL query.

Comment: Or maybe you know how to add leading zeros to month values? It will somehow bypass problem

Comment: `peewee.__version__` gives `2.10.2`